# How to create email address which not affect when servers changing?

Tags: dns, email, zoho

I change namservers almost every year because I change web hosting companies.

I have plan to use Zoho for my emails.

So how to create email address which not affect when servers changing? I mean even I change nameservers emails should be working without a problem.

Comment: "I change nameservers almost every year because I change web hosting companies." ...  WHY????      Just leave your nameservers as is and change your A and CNAME records when you change hosting companies.    Many domain registrars such as GoDaddy offer free DNS hosting with domain registration, so it is usually cheap to host your DNS with your registrar.   I purchase DNS hosting from a third party company (not my domain registrar, nor my web hest).  Even for a high traffic site you can get DNS hosting for $10 a year or so.

Comment: Why? Because to get the discount. I mean generally renew fee for shared hosting 150$.... But I can get new one around 50$ per year because of discount. So I move hostagor to bluehost, then bluehost to inmostion, again hostgator, etc.

My all domain names are in namecheap. they also offer free DNS. Then I can use it, isn't?

Comment: What is the "affect" on the email address that is the main concern?

Comment: @DocRoot Even I change nameservers, email should works without any problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an email account that is not affected (at all) by a server change you would need to use a third party email service (like Zoho, GSuite, etc.) that *does not change*.

Changing NAMESERVERS would still be "OK", providing the appropriate `MX` records are preconfigured at the new DNS.

Answer (score 4):

Use some sort of 3rd party DNS hosting provider.  Someone above mentioned your Registrar (Dynadot, GoDaddy, etc) but you can also use something like CloudFlare as well.

When you change hosts, you just log into CloudFlare to change your A record.   You add your Zoho MX records from them as well